# Meteor js: separating front end from back end

Tags: javascript, meteor

So the whole point of `meteor js` is to allow the user to code the whole stack at once, but if I were working on one of the older frameworks like `django`, could I borrow the front end code from `meteor js`? For example, the front end syncing of the database, the templating, or how meteor handles events with the template, etc.

Is there a way to extract `meteor js` front end code to be used in an another framework?

Comment: Doing that would be more work than just using all Meteor.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no such method. The whole point of Meteor (well, one of key points at least) is to have one framework that works both on front end and back end. That way you don't have to write two separate logic layers, nor additional layer for communication between them. It's a really big advantage.

That said, you could theoretically use Meteor front end with django back end, provided that you talk to the server manually with AJAX and wrap the data with your own reactivity. However, you'll end up rewriting a large part of Meteor yourself. It'll be much easier to either rewrite the old django code in Meteor, or use a dedicated front-end framework like Backbone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Django DDP](https://github.com/commoncode/django-ddp) to provide a Meteor backend from your Django project -- including realtime, latency-compensated publications/subscriptions and remote procedure calls (RPC).  Have a look at the examples in the README and in the [examples in the repo](https://github.com/commoncode/django-ddp/tree/develop/dddp/test) for inspiration.

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of django-ddp.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it work.

If you write a DDP server that talk to the Meteor front end.  And you could publish whatever data you want through DDP to a client only collection. (here is a link on how to https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/feed-archive/how-to-publish-to-a-client-only-collection).

And on the front end you just need to use DDP.connect(server URL) to connect the server.